# Add multiple puts in a block

Tags: ruby

Whats the difference between this 2? why one works and the other does not?

```
array.each{ |item| puts "The item is #{item}" puts item + 1 }

array.each do |item|
  puts "The item is #{item}"
  puts item + 1
end
```

Comment: Because you're missing a semicolon / newline on the first one between the `puts` statements?

Answer (score 5):

When you have two statements in a single line, you need to put a `;` between the two. Thus: `puts "The item is #{item}"; puts item + 1`.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to cram two expressions where only one is expected. You can separate the two expressions using a semicolon:

```
array.each { |item| puts "The item is #{item}"; puts item + 1 }
```

Why not just supply both `"The item is #{item}"` and `item + 1` to `puts`?

```
array.each { |item| puts "The item is #{item}", item + 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array.each{ |item| puts "The item is #{item}" puts item + 1 }
```

This is simply a syntax error, as mentioned by your interpreter:

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting '}'
```

Your second example is syntactically correct and so does not raise an error.

```
array.each do |item|
  puts "The item is #{item}"
  puts item + 1
end
```

You are missing a space after the `each` method call, before the first `{` which is perhaps at best a bad habit.

Also, you can have your first example as:

```
array.each {|item| puts "The item is #{item}"
  puts item + 1 }
```

And it would become syntactically correct, because of the new line.  Nothing says that the curly brace form of a block given to each has to be written on one line, though it is one common convention.

For style, though, (and this is not [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), I know), I would probably try to keep the code consistent.

```
array.each do |item|
  puts "The item is #{item}\n#{item.next}"
end
```

Or perhaps with the curly braces:

```
array.each do { |item| puts "The item is #{item}\n#{item.next}" }
```